# When I do document preview it will logout first time?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-ide, liferay-velocity

I have liferay open office integration. My problem is when I preview any document after login first time it is logout and ask to login again. Next time it is working fine the problem persist while document preview generation and after user log first time. suppose there are 5 page of document only 2 page display other while show processing image.

Below are logs come while logout.

```
06:55:17,743 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-88][PollerServlet:63] No channel exists with user id 1810503
06:55:17,782 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-88][status_jsp:752] No channel exists with user id 1810503
06:55:26,360 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-95][PollerServlet:63] No channel  exists with user id 1810503
06:55:26,403 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-95][status_jsp:752] No channel exists with user id 1810503
```

Above logs come each time when i log in.

I am using Liferay 6.2 CE GA3 + Mysql + Openoffice + xuggler.

I have seen liferay issues related with No channel exists with user id but it does not answer my question

Comment: Could you clarify, what you mean with _login first time_? First login after the user was created or first login after the browser was opened or something else? And are the logs the result of login or logout?

Comment: Hi Tobias ,                                                                                              Thanks for comment.                                                                            The log coming when the user login and when Logout error occurred both. First Login after browser opened this type of error occurred.  The error can come anytime but for first time it is surely come and user is logout.

Comment: HI Tobias                                                                                                    I also found that If the preview not generate for some pages then also user logout. E.g. I have PDF file which have 90 Pages sometime what happen It unable genarate preview for lets say 81 , 82 , 83 page then also user logout and asking for login again.

Comment: Sounds like a proxy problem to me. Could you describe your infrastructure? I mean, are you testing on localhost?

Comment: We are using liferay 2 Application server and integrated with open office. We are using MYSql as database.

Comment: Did you test it on your local machine as well? What kind of loadbalancer are you using? Is there a proxy between you and your loadbalancer?